# Javascript: function with "this" undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and am attempting to write a function that changes the color of some text, however "this" keeps returning as undefine, and not changing the text color. 
Here's the code, I would greatly appreciate some help.

```
<h1>
    <ul><div class="info" id="info" onclick="this.style.color= '#9DC8BA'">INFO
    </div></ul>
    <ul><div class="menu" id="menu" onclick="test1()"<!--this is where the problem is-->MENU</div></ul>
```

Here's the Javascript

```
function test1() {
this.style.color= '#9DC8BA';
}
```

Comment: Change `=test1()` to `=test1(this)`, and `function test1()` to `function test1(div) {div.style.color='#CCC'}`.

Comment: Your markup is invalid, a DIV can't be a child of a UL. In non–strict mode, *this* is never undefined. If not set in the call, or by *bind*, it will default to the global (window in a browser) object. Likely the console is complaining that *window.style* is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to pass the reference of the DOM element to the function

```
<div class="menu" id="menu" onclick="test1(this)">/div>
```

in the above html, this refers the current DOM element which is a DIV of id menu.

and then refer and modify the DOM inside the function

```
function test1(obj) {
   obj.style.color= '#9DC8BA';
}
```

Side note: You seem to be having a same name for class and id for the div, which is not a good practice.
Always remember Class corresponds to a group of elements and ID corresponds to unique elements.

Comment: Thank you so much Prabhu, I apologize for wasting your time with such a simple solution, but thank you.

Comment: He don't `have to`. There is another solution.

Comment: @Epsilon: i'm sorry did i miss something here.

Comment: @Prabhu Your solutions works perfectly, just there is another way, that's all I am saying. If you set function from JavaScript, then `this` will work.

Answer (score 1):

test1 function is executed not on the div element as context but on window.

do this:

```
onclick="test1(this)"
```

in function:

```
function test1(div) {
    div.style.color = '#9DC8BA';
}
```

Comment: *this* is not "context", it is a parameter of an [*execution context*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-execution-contexts). ;-)

Comment: I explained the current issue. As a solution, the context is being passed as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Html Code

```
<h1>
    <ul><div class="info" id="info" onclick="this.style.color= '#9DC8BA'">INFO
    </div></ul>
    <ul><div class="menu" id="menu" onclick="test1(this)">MENU</div></ul>
 </h1>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
function test1(obj) 
{ 
   obj.style.color= '#9DC8BA'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing `onclick` inside the html, it makes new function itself.
In your case it is something like `function(){test1()}`. `this` inside this function is what you need, but `this` inside the `test1` is undefined.

You can use `this` as argument of `test1`

```
... onclick="test1(this)" ...
```

and JS

```
function test1(obj) {
```

And use `obj` instead of `this` in `test1`

Or set function `onclick` attribute from javascript like:

```
var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
menu.onclick = test1;
```

In this case `this` inside the `test1` will be exactly what you need.